# iOS - Convert NSArray to float array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have this an array called `self.gradientArray` of colors. When I print it out it looks like this:

```
gradientsArray: (
    "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.333333 0.811765 0.768627 1",
    "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.333333 0.811765 0.768627 1" )
```

I want to convert this array into a CGFloat array. An example is like this:

```
CGFloat colors [] = {
                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
            };
```

I tried this and it didn't work. I'm new to Objective-C and the syntax so please help me.

```
CGFloat colors [] = self.gradientArray;
```

I want to use the CGFloat array in making gradients like this:

```
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
```

Comment: enumerate  objects use NSArray *stringArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]; and do it

Comment: @PKT I don't think he really has an array of strings. I think he has a `NSArray` of `UIColor` objects, which, when you `NSLog` it, generates output much like he shared in his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gradientsArray` would appear to be an array of `UIColor`, in which case you could do something like:

```
NSArray *gradientsArray = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor]];

CGFloat colors[gradientsArray.count * 4];
NSInteger index = 0;
for (UIColor *color in gradientsArray) {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    colors[index++] = red;
    colors[index++] = green;
    colors[index++] = blue;
    colors[index++] = alpha;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Rob!

Comment: @Rob CGFloat colors[gradientsArray.count * 4]; What does 4 represents here ??

Comment: The OP wanted to populate his/her `CGFloat` array to be supplied to [`CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1398454-cggradientcreatewithcolorcompone?language=occ) with four component values of each color in the gradient array, namely each color’s respective red, blue, green, and alpha values.